# Когда ставится тире в предложении с двоеточием?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, двоеточие

> Наши вожатые: Аня, Коля и Миша — были великолепны.

Недавно я увидела похожий пример использования 
тире и не поняла, почему оно употребляется в данном предложении.
Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить, а заодно подкрепить свой ответ примером.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Первый вариант:

Аня, Коля и Миша можно рассматривать как однородные члены предложения, стоящие после обобщающего слова. Но они не заканчивают собой предложения, поэтому перед ними ставится двоеточие, а после — тире:

Наши вожатые: Аня, Коля и Миша – были великолепны.

Второй вариант:

Собственные имена могут быть обособленными приложениями и выделять тире с двух сторон:

Наши вожатые - Аня, Коля и Миша – были великолепны.

Третий вариант:

Можно считать вожатые приложением, а слова Аня, Коля и Миша - определяемыми словами, тогда:

Наши вожатые Аня, Коля и Миша были великолепны.

Как пишет Розенталь, общее понятие факультативности в употреблении знаков препинания допускает выделение трех случаев:

1) знак собственно факультативный — по схеме «знак — нуль знака» (ставить или не ставить); И когда(,) месяц спустя(,) мы вернулись к этому разговору, тема его потеряла уже свою остроту;

2) знак альтернативный — по схеме «или — или» (взаимоисключение знаков); Отряд остановился: у переправы не было лодок. — Отряд остановился у переправы: не было лодок

3) знак вариативный — по схеме «знак на выбор» (параллельное употребление знаков). Его ничто не берёт (: — ) ни время, ни невзгоды, ни болезни;

Comment: То есть все варианты равноправны?

Answer (score 0):

1. Наши вожатые: Аня, Коля и Миша – были великолепны.
2. Наши вожатые — Аня, Коля и Миша – были великолепны.
3. Наши вожатые Аня, Коля и Миша были великолепны.

Первые два предложения практически не отличаются по смыслу. Все вожатые перечислены.
Третье предложение построено так, что невозможно сказать, сколько было всего вожатых.